# A classical analysis problem

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Define $$x_{k+1}(t)=\frac{3x^4_k(t)+6(1-t)x_k^2(t)-(1-t)^2}{8x_k^3(t)},$$
 with $x_0(t)=1$. It is not difficult to see $x_k(t)$ converges to $\sqrt{1-t}$, whose (Maclaurin expansion) has negative coefficients unless the first one. Let

$$x_k(t)=\sum\limits_{i =0}^{\infty}c_{k,i}t^{i}, \mid t\mid<1$$

Is it true $c_{k,i}\le0$ for all $k\ge 1, i\ge 1$?

Comment: First of all, there is a "classical-analysis" tag. Secondly, renormalising $y_k(t)=x_k(t)/\sqrt{1-t}$ (so that your recurrence relation does not depend on $t$) I see that $y_k(t)$ converges to 1 pretty fast (faster than Pade approximations). This means that your sequence approached $\sqrt{1-t}$ which has all ($k>0$) coefficients negative. I just wonder whether you can give details of your construction in order to make these observations rigorous and to attack your problem.

Comment: Thanks, Zudilin, I think the statement of the problem is now clear.

Comment: The problem was already correct! I wonder whether you can give some motivation to study this positivity: this might be helpful. The observation I have for your sequence are: (1) $x_k(t)$ is the quotient of two polynomials of degree $2^{2k-1}$ and $2^{2k-1}-2$ for $k\ge1$ (this can be extracted from the recursion modulo irredicibility); (2) $x_k(t)-\sqrt{1-t}=O(t^{3^k})$ for $k\ge0$ and the $t$-expansion of $x_k-\sqrt{1-t}$ involves positive coefficients only. The only thing I can show is that starting with $x_0=1-t$ one gets $x_k/\sqrt{1-t}$ with negative coefficients besides the constant term

Comment: Dear Russel, from your comment above I can see that the truth for $1\le i\le 3^k$ wasn't known to you. This was my reasoning for giving more details. In order to attack your problem one needs a better formula for $x_k(t)$. I know of many unsolved problems on positivity and my reasons to do them are their serious motivation and recognised hardness. Your problem is curious, seemingly hard and that's all. Besides two of us nobody tried to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not the first time I am fighting with positivity (nonnegativity).
But this problem looks not natural enough for a standard technique, and
it seems to me that the resulting sequence $x_k(t)$ is always between
$\sqrt{1-t}$ and $1$, in the sense that the expansions of $x_k(t)-\sqrt{1-t}$
and $1-x_k(t)$ have nonnegative coefficients only.

I can only give a partial solution. After the change
$$
z_k(t)=1-\frac{x_k(t)}{\sqrt{1-t}}
$$
the recursion for $x_k(t)$ translates into
$$
z_{k+1}=\frac{z_k^3(4-3z_k)}{8(1-z_k)^3}
\quad\text{for}\quad k=0,1,2,\dots
$$
with the initial data
$$
z_0=1-\frac1{\sqrt{1-t}}=-\frac12t+O(t^2).
$$
The recursion implies $z_{k+1}=z_k^3/2+O(z_k^4)$, therefore
by induction on $k$ we obtain
$$
z_k=-\frac{t^{3^k}}{2^{(3^{k+1}-1)/2}}+\text{higher terms}.
$$
This implies that
$$
x_k(t)=\sqrt{1-t}-\sqrt{1-t}z_k(t)
$$
agrees with $\sqrt{1-t}$ up to the term $t^{3^k}$. In particular,
as the expansion of $\sqrt{1-t}$ involves negative coefficients besides
the constant term, we conclude that $c_{k,i}<0$ for $i=1,2,\dots,3^k$
in the expansion
$$
x_k(t)=1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty c_{k,i}t^i.
$$

Comment: The above reasoning is standard. I also obtain this partial solution.

Comment: Then it's not very fair to put the problem without providing information of this sort. The idea of MO is not giving solutions but helping with references and possible approaches. In several cases (and I am aware of examples), somebody indicates some vague ideas and then others use them to elaborate a solution.

Comment: The above partial solution (which deserves one vote up) is all I know concerning this problem. This is a technical problem, it is a matter of time to solve it.